# why permission of file changes after uploading file using sftp?

Tags: linux, file, ssh, sftp, openssh

Suppose The file permission at local machine is 644 
and using openssh (sftp) /putty ssh if i upload file to remote
file permission in remote machine changed to 640 Why ?

What we have to do we we need same permision ?

SFTP library implemneted by us
Lang :  C

Comment: Is this related to programming? If no, then it's offtopic here. if yes, then specify what language / environment you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the umask, which affects the default permissions for newly created files. You can use the `umask` command to change this, if the remote server allows it.

Comment: Thanks for reply, After upload I have to send UMASK or in upload cmd itself we can send umask

Comment: You need to set the umask, and then start uploading. Your current umask determines what the permissions of a newly created file will be.

Comment: I want to know , Why when upload is done , if local permission is wrxwrxwrx then in remore write permision removed , remote file permission is rwxr_xr_x   for group and others write permision reved automaticaly why ?

Comment: Perhaps the best thing is if you were to read more about umask: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask (Google might provide some more accessible docs if Wikipedia's page is too technical).

Answer (score 0):

Either what @pgl said, or use a program that actually sets the file mode after transfer, such as rsync(-over-ssh).